# How do i join two texts together

Tags: animation, text-object

I have 2 texts, and I want to move them both so it looks like its just one text. How do I combine both of the texts so that I can keyframe just to one?
Do I just have to copy the numbers from one over to the other or can I combine them like I want? I have tried shift clicking then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and it doesn't work.

Comment: You may parent both texts to the Empty and animate Empty's transformations. See related btw: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36908/letter-by-letter-animation

Comment: You want two "words" in one text object?

Comment: Of course, if you don't need to edit them later as "text", you can convert both to objects with ALT + C and then join them with CTRL + J

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to simply parent one to the other - transforming the parent will then similarly affect the child.

Select the second text object and then hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and select the one you want to use as the controlling object. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to set the parent and make parent. Moving, scaling or rotating the parent should now affect the child as if they were one. If you want to link more than just two Text objects then simply select more by clicking them while still holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key - just make sure the last one you select is the one you want as the 'parent'.

To prevent accidentally grabbing and manipulating the wrong one, select the child and set each of the Transform Locks in the object properties panel to a padlock and you'll no longer be able to manipulate that object in the 3D view.