# Make 2 Objects Have Same Rotation

Tags: python

So I have the following situation:

I have 2 objects: object A has no rotation(Since the rotation has been applied via ctrl-a) and object B has a random rotation. Now I want to make object A have the same rotation as Object B.  My guess is that  I somehow have to get the obj B rotation as a vector and then aim obj A in that direction. The thing is that I have to have the exact same rotation as obj B has. (If the rot of obj B is greater than 360, then obj A rot doesn’t have to be greater than 360, it should just aim in the same direction and the roll/yaw/pitch should be exactly the same. 
So how can I achieve this via Python?

Comment: You may parent both objects to an Empty or give them a 'copy rotation' constraint with an Empty set as a target. Please see related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36908/letter-by-letter-animation

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to copy the rotation values, there is "Copy Rotation" in the Constraints tab, no need for Python scripts. If you need it for a Python script, objects have [`rotation_euler`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_euler), [`rotation_quaternion`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_quaternion), and [`rotation_axis_angle`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_axis_angle) attributes, and [`rotation_mode`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_mode) for selecting one of them.

Comment: There is also `rotation_axis_angle` and `rotation_mode` is used to determine which rotation value is used.

Comment: @sambler For some reason I have seen those during testing and quickly ignored them thinking that they are unimportant. That was a silly thing to do. Thank you for the additional information.