# How do I rotate some text?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, text-object

I'm making a logo in blender. I originally converted a PNG to SVG and then imported it to Blender but that made a really messy mesh. So now I'm making it straight in blender.

Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

I basically just typed it out and then extruded it using the Solidify modifier.

But I can't rotate it, or move it. I tried converting it to curve and then mesh but it still won't rotate. Also converting it messes up the mesh pretty bad.

[image]

Any clue what's going on?

Also if there are ways I could improve my workflow, let me know. Is there a better way to extrude the text? I also plan on curving it around a circle, towards the camera (so not like around a ball like you would see in photoshop but in the 3rd dimension like a hug or something)

Comment: Related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36908/letter-by-letter-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you 'typed it out' in Blender I'm assuming you used the text tool. If that is the case, then you have been wasting time, since it is still a curve object and will also have a messed up topology.

Text tools are just a special type of Bezier curve objects, so if you plan on converting to mesh might as well have just used the one imported from SVG you already had directly.

Curve objects are actually an underrated and powerful modeling tool to use, **if** you don't plan on converting to a mesh object later. That will often lead to triangulated uneven topology, unless you do some serious manual cleanup work.

If you don't plan on doing any heavy edits and shape modifications I'd recommend leaving them as curves objects.

Create your text then in Object Mode press Alt + C > *Convert to Curve*, then use the built in curve properties (not a *Solidify* modifier) for extrusion. You'll have the added benefit of procedural non destructive beveling and allow easy tweaking of the character's shapes by controlling the bezier curve handles in edit mode.

About rotation I'm assuming you want to rotate each character individually, if that's the case you either have to rotate them in *Edit Mode* individually (after converting to Bezier Curve or Mesh) or separate each character into it's own object (L to select all linked geometry and P to separate), then rotating each individually in *Object Mode*

If you plan on doing geometry heavy changes to you logo however, then I'd recommend a different approach and start from scratch modeling you logo as a mesh. It may be harder at the beginning, but with a good starting topology it may well compensate in the long run

Comment: This is helpful for my workflow, but the actual rotation issue was fixed here: https://vimeo.com/30128400

Turns out I accidently had hit a toggle on rotation down at the bottom.

Comment: Hey @duarte I tried your work flow suggestions but I ran into other issues. I created a separate question. Maybe you would be able to help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63538/why-does-my-extruded-text-go-wonky-like-this-why-does-my-text-go-weird-when-i-c

Answer (score -2):

Right click on it then hit <kbd>R</kbd>, to rotate. Hope this helps!

Comment: We favor more complete and elaborate answers here at Blender Stack Exchange, with complete information and helpful instructions