# Why does my extruded text go wonky like this? Why does my text go weird when I convert it to a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, text-object, extrude

I am making a 3D logo.

When I create a text object and use solidify mod to make it thicker it does this:

[image]

When I don't use the solid mod, and instead convert it to a curve to do a curve extrusion it does this:

[image]

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try using the text settings rather than manually extruding it? [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/anj99.gif]

Comment: Excellent thank you very much. This worked!

Comment: Also,  If I then convert this into a mesh or curve later will that mess it up? I want to eventually port this stuff to Unity.

Comment: @DavidA.French Try it! I am fairly certain it will work. If not, just convert it to a mesh.

Comment: I actually have a problem before that. I need to do some editing on it's composition before using it in Unity but it's acting super janky once I convert it to a Mesh. :( http://i.imgur.com/nwKU8ZR.png

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening. I think it is because the letters are connected. If in wireframe mode the model looks good, you could probably manually fix the faces.

Answer (score 2):

The missing fill in your curves is caused by overlap. If the curves self intersect Blender doesn't know how to fill them correctly.

Either:

- Move them slightly apart in edit mode (just enough not to overlap), or
- Use the offset option in *Properties Window > Object Data (Curves) > Transform > Offset* (be careful as too much offset will cause problems of their own) ; or
- If you really must leave them exactly as they are optionally use a different material slot on each independent spline (this is a workaround for the problem but kind of works because Blender wont try to fill them together).

Again if you are working with curves don't use the solidify modifier, instead use the curve extrude option which should yield better results.

That being said, I think you started on the wrong foot, if you plan on curving your object the way you show in the image you will never get a clean solution from curves. Because of the triangle based topology  of curve object you will never get a clean smooth curvature.

You can try and minimize it by using a *Subsurf* modifier but it will generally maintain it's triangulated appearance.

You should do this from scratch with a mesh object with an even quad based topology

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot. I ended up getting it to work using the extrude text function. If I then convert this into a mesh or curve later will that mess it up? I want to eventually port this stuff to Unity.

Comment: No, converting to mesh or curve should maintain it as is, just have in mind that converting to mesh is a 'destructive process' in the sense that you cant go back to a curve cleanly, so remember to keep a copy of the original object around.

Comment: Hmmm I just tried converting it to a curve and it did indeed mess it up. That was after I had applied a simple deform mod, so I'm going to try and see if holding off on applying that helps.

Comment: This is how it ends up looking. Getting rid of the deform mod doesn't help. I realize that maybe this is just a problem with this font being poorly formatted but I had this same problem yesterday. I went through 7 hours of painstaking clean up. I tried using a PNG converted to SVG but it converted poorly and the points were all janky so I basically had to completely rebuild the extruded stuff. I thought a font would be cleaner.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nwKU8ZR.png

Comment: As I mentioned, if you plan on deforming this you are better of start using a mesh object purposefully modeled from for this, Curves don't deform too well

Comment: You mean the best method is to make the text object and then hand box model a mesh that looks like it? 

I guess you mean like with the SVG. But like I said the SVG gave me some really bad output all. I guess if I build it in Illustrator natively, cutting out the PNG step that might improve things but it seems like the path for this font might just be hard for Blender to read?

Comment: Yes I mean box model it by hand with a mesh over the font object as visual guide. It's a lot of work, but all other curve based solutions (text object, SVG, Traced PNG, Illustrator or otherwise) will suffer the same triangulation issues

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have one last question. I actually retried the SVG without going through the PNG conversion step and it came out much better, super easy to extrude, no problems. But when I do the final step to convert it into a mesh, the result mesh is very unsightly. In researching this I've seen stuff like the remesh mod. Would a mod like that help at all? Or something else?

Comment: Never used it myself but yes, sounds like it might help. Of course it is never as good as well thought out manual topology, but for this case since it's just a deform modifier it may suffice